# ggplot2 legend: different colors for geom_point and geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to make a graph that includes both points and lines; I've been using a consistent set of color/fill/shape combinations for the levels of my grouping factor (Condition) throughout a set of graphs that only have points, so I want to keep those the same in this graph as well.  However, I now also want to add some lines, and wish to manually specify the line colors.  So far so good; the trouble is that I'd really like the graph to have a single legend that shows the color/fill/shape for the points as well as the color and line type of the lines.  Does anyone have any ideas about how to achieve this, perhaps with the new guide legend stuff (which I have not yet wrapped my head around)?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

(Also, if this helps explain why I'm trying to do things this way, the data consist of samples that started out in Condition B, and were moved to Condition C; I'm trying to highlight what happens to dv when that change is made.  For reference, I'm also showing data from samples maintained in Condition B or Condition C throughout the experiment, but I don't want those lines to be as prominent, since they aren't the point of the graph.)

How can I get the line color in the legend to match the line color in the graph?

[image]

```
mydata <- structure(list(Condition = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L), .Label =
c("CondA", "CondB", "CondC", "CondD", "BeforeChange", "AfterChange"), class =
"factor"), Day = c(1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 1,
3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 13, 14, 14), dv = c(7.18272766270665,
7.42730999263847, 7.66391016865676, 7.602389725654, 7.39221477975877,
7.46192935291398, 7.62075582981643, 7.47839284216667, 6.56987476062938,
6.69091456174267, 6.6697752192633, 6.35890571005243, 6.93927313468223,
6.65712651759238, 6.93055110758838, 7.0391827047215, 7.15066983259602,
7.59782467658902, 7.59892456901464, 7.42888298870538, 7.49983551294577,
7.30476290695126, 6.99896760719176, 6.97838387933162, 7.434811, 7.369787,
7.369787 ), se = c(0.152197789175902, 0.0396497303055128, 0.0506439629227802, 
0.109997525500822, 0.114500535946067, 0.0736412492173867, 0.111473540926106, 
0.0808019418670817, 0.133004775453176, 0.134977834863898, 0.167639712420762, 
0.25651178518586, 0.0717077961089037, 0.164745732598605, 0.171383889660418, 
0.133281180227772, 0.230898256311926, 0.178695661660643, 0.0427233153730758, 
0.105571418251551, 0.10389399069655, 0.110566732681714, 0.152512756205137, 
0.0759939810936424, 0.106119, 0.108343, 0.108343)), .Names = c("Condition", "Day",
"dv", "se"), row.names = 9:35, class = "data.frame")

require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(grid)

ggplot() +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(2.5, "lines")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("CondB" = "white", "CondC" = "black", "BeforeChange" = "white", "AfterChange" = "black"), breaks = c("CondB", "CondC", "BeforeChange", "AfterChange")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("CondB" = "grey30", "CondC" = "grey50", "BeforeChange" = "grey30", "AfterChange" = "grey50"), breaks = c("CondB", "CondC", "BeforeChange", "AfterChange")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("CondB" = 22, "CondC" = 21, "BeforeChange" = 22, "AfterChange" = 21), breaks = c("CondB", "CondC", "BeforeChange", "AfterChange")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("CondB" = "dashed", "CondC" = "longdash", "BeforeChange" = "solid", "AfterChange" = "solid"), breaks = c("CondB", "CondC", "BeforeChange", "AfterChange")) + 

  geom_line(data = mydata[mydata$Condition %in% c("CondB"), ], aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(Day)), y=dv, group=Condition, linetype = Condition), color = "grey60") + 
  geom_line(data = mydata[mydata$Condition %in% c("CondC"), ], aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(Day)), y=dv, group=Condition, linetype = Condition), color = "grey50") + 
  geom_line(data = mydata[mydata$Condition %in% c("BeforeChange"), ], aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(Day)), y=dv, linetype = Condition), color = "grey30") + 
  geom_line(data = mydata[mydata$Condition %in% c("AfterChange"), ], aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(Day)), y=dv, linetype = Condition), color = "black") + 

  geom_point(data = mydata[mydata$Condition %in% c("CondB", "CondC", "BeforeChange", "AfterChange") & mydata$Day %in% c(1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21), ], aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(Day)), y=dv, color = Condition, fill = Condition, shape = Condition), size=3) + 

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 5:8, labels = math_format(10^.x)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=14, y=7.77, xend=14, yend=7.41), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", angle = 20), size=0.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the aesthetics of the legend with `override.aes` in `guide_legend`.  However, I initially had trouble changing the color because I usually use `color` instead of `colour` and that didn't work here.

```
guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c("grey60", "grey50", "grey30", "black"))))
```

The downside of this is that the color will also change for the outline of your points and your legend points no longer quite match your graphic.  You could consider making your lines the same color as your point outlines.